# How to translate Ordinary scancodes to ascii charcters

Tags: c++, encryption, keyboard, scancodes

I'm need to convert these scans code to ascii charters.

in this website :
[1.4 Ordinary scancodes](https://oelzant.at/%7Eaoe/mystuff/agenda/kbd-1.05/doc/scancodes/scancodes-1.html)

for example :

```
char scan_codes[]={ 0x1e,0x1e,0x1f,0x1f,0x20,0x20 };

char* result = translate_keys(scan_codes);
//output after translation could be      result = "aassdd"
```

is there any mathematical equation to convert this or how to build translate_keys() function in C++ ?

Comment: There's no mathematicall equation. You just have some tedious programming to do.

Comment: There might be some repositories on github already done it and you may take it as an reference.

Comment: @LouisGo can you share some links I searched so much

Comment: I use keyword "scan code to ascii conversion github" on google and there are [some results](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03gzsfvZZ0jJtDxC9zt47x-VOyIxQ%3A1595895834020&ei=GnAfX5dtmJGvvA_s2anoAw&q=scan+code+to+ascii+conversion+github&oq=scan+code+to+ascii+conversion+github&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECCMQJzoECAAQHjoFCCEQoAE6BwghEAoQoAFQkeACWO_3AmCV-QJoBHAAeACAAT2IAfoEkgECMTKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiX4qOi1-7qAhWYyIsBHexsCj0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)